# Adding a conditional to work on certain pages/page templates to an add_action()

Tags: actions

```
function wpufe_auto_login_new_user( $user_id ) {   
    wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, false, is_ssl() );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'wpufe_auto_login_new_user' );
```

I'm using the above function to automatically login a person after registration. It is for a specific use case and I would like to make it only work for a particular page or template where the form exists. Would this be possible?

Also, what might be the best way to add a page redirect to it? wp_redirect() possibly? I would like to redirect after the function fires.

Update:

I've tried the below conditional as a page id as well as a page name 'My Page' and it makes the action not fire at all over all forms on the site.

```
function wpufe_auto_login_new_user( $user_id ) {   
if ( is_page( 3943 )) {    
    wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, false, is_ssl() );
    }
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'wpufe_auto_login_new_user' );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function wpufe_auto_login_new_user( $user_id ) { 
     if ( is_page( 'Page Title' ){  
          wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
          wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, false, is_ssl() );
     }
}
```

Yes.  I would use  wp_redirect().  If your are redirecting from some other page to the login page. But I am unsure what you want to redirect to or where from.

Comment: That actually made my function not fire at all. I have updated my question above.